# Searching in listview while typing in textbox using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I used OnKeyUp so while user is typing, it is searching in the list view. I am getting an error with my code.

> "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Here is my code below:

```
Private Sub txtEmailGenSearch_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As
    MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim strText As String
    Dim i As Long

    strText = LCase(txtSearch.value)
    With MainForm.lstMailGen
        For i = 0 To .ListItems.count - 1
            If LCase(Left(.ListItems(i, 0), Len(strText))) = strText Then 
                Exit For

        Next i

        If i = .ListItems.count Then
            ' No matching item was found, select nothing
            .ListIndex = -1
        Else
            ' A match was found, select it
            .ListIndex = i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is your issue? What's wrong with your code? You need to ask something if you want us to answer (see [ask]).

Comment: In which line do you get the error? You need to be as specific and detailed as possible. • Note that your `If LCase … Then` statement has no `End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView is quite different from a ListBox. Each row in a ListView is a ListItem.  If the ListView has multiple columns then each ListItem will contain ListSubItems.  This applies to a Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 Listview, 5.0 works a little different. ListViews do not return a 2D array like a ListBox does have have a ListIndex property.

Recommended Reading: [Excel VBA ListView Control Examples](https://10tec.com/articles/excel-vba-listview-control-examples.aspx)

Use `ListItem.Find()` to locate a matching ListItem

> ```
> With MainForm.lstMailGen
>     Dim item As ListItem
>     Set item = .FindItem(sz:=txtSearch.value, fPartial:=lvwPartial)
>     If Not item Is Nothing Then
>         item.Selected = True
>     End If
> End With
> ```

In for the ListItem to be hightlighted make sure that `HideSelection = False`

> ```
> MainForm.lstMailGen.HideSelection = False
> ```

The Listitems first index is 1 not 0.

> ```
>  For i = 1 To .ListItems.Count 
>      If LCase(Left(.ListItems(i), Len(strText))) = strText Then 
>         Exit For
>  Next i
> ```

If the last item contained the string than `If i = .ListItems.count Then` would skip the selection.  `If i > .ListItems.count Then` is the right way to do this.  If the `For` loop completes then `i` will be incremented an extra time.  In the above case `i` would = .ListItems.Count + 1` if the loop completed.

Comment: Hi I keep getting an error in the `.ListItems(i,0)` part. It says Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: @RobinScherbatsky I made an error editing the code.  In any case `.ListItems` is a collection not a 2D array.  Use `.ListItems(i)`.  If the value is in the second column you would use `.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(1).